# @OnClick doesn't works after rotation in ButterKnife

Tags: android, butterknife

I have the next fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ButterKnife.setDebug(true);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.button)
    public void onButtonClicked () {
        //Do some stuff
    }
}
```

OnClick method works like a charm first time and it works fine until I rotate the device. When I rotate the device, method doesn't works more.

Log has no errors.

Do you know what is the problem?

Thanks you.

Comment: What happens if you move your code from onViewCreated to onCreateView?

Comment: @Hasslarn it happens the same

Comment: Still no answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to retain the fragment to avoid to be destroyed and created again.It may resolve you problem

Comment: I am looking for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Try unbinding when the fragment is destroyed (which should happen upon rotation). Then it should bind correctly again:

```
@Override 
public void onDestroyView(){
    super.onDestroyView();
    ButterKnife.unbind(this);
}
```